# What happens to Excel Workbooks if called in multiple threads during cycle?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, excel-interop

Suppose I have a piece of code, which does the following:

1. Opens a new `Excel.Workbook` (let's call it `NewBook`) and initializes it by filling it with some data.
2. [Does stuff here].
3. Passes the `Excel.Workbook` to another variable (`OldBook`).
4. Opens another thread to fill `OldBook` with more data, *while* the main thread begins again the cycle from step 1.

Now, I would expect that if I assigned `OldBook = NewBook` during step 3, I actually would have *pointed* to the object.
Since step 1 of cycle 2 would change the `NewBook` variable (by opening a new `Workbook`), does `OldBook` of cycle 1 change its `Workbook` address while executing?

Just an example (written in VB.NET - Please assume each variable to be `Dim`ed outside this `For` cycle.

```vb
For FileCounter = 0 To MaxFiles
    NewBook = Excel.Workbooks.Add
    Initialize_Excel(NewBook) ' Does stuff with NewBook
    OldBook = NewBook
    ' [Does stuff here]
    ParallelThread = New Thread(AddressOf Complete_Excel)
    ParallelThread.Start(OldBook) ' Does stuff with OldBook, but parallely
Next
```

Comment: In step 3 you mentioned Excel.Workbook to OldBook and below the steps you've mentioned OldBook=NewBook ?! That's not same. Could you please copy paste C# code?

Comment: Well yes, you first open a Workbook (Newbook), then you do some stuff, then you assign the same Workbook to another variable, open a new thread, and do some stuff with it, while the main thread continues. The main thread could possibly open another Newbook, while Oldbook is still being modified by the parallel thread. I can paste some VB.NET code, but this is not really something I wrote, in fact it is just a question to understand how those things work

Comment: The code snippet you've put doesn't show if variables are declared within ForLoop scope or not. Should we assume it is in the ForLoop scope? or the containing method scope? What is AddressOf Complete_Excel ? what does Initialize_Excel do?

Comment: Variables are declared outside the For cycle. `Complete_Excel` is a function that does [insert whatever here] with the workbook passed as argument.`Initialize_Excel` does [some stuff] to the workbook passed as an argument.